# Headers already sent error with get_template_part in REST API call

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I've looked at multiple other questions about this warning (Headers already sent...etc) and [this thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/11855303), but I'm not finding a solution for the circumstances I'm dealing with:

1. I have a custom Wordpress REST API endpoint that **returns the output of `get_template_part`**. When I just call `get_template_part` normally on a page, there's no warning. It only appears when it runs in `register_rest_route`'s callback.
2. I am also fetching data from an external API using [this library](https://github.com/aredotna/arena-php). The error started when I started making these requests. I've tried making the request both inside and outside the template part, the latter either within `register_rest_route`'s callback or as an `init` action.
3. The line that triggers the error is an `img` tag, where I'm `echo`-ing a URL as the `src` using data from the external API response. There are other `echo` calls all over this template, so I doubt that's the issue.
4. The line in question actually works fine and does its job. I just need to get rid of the accursed warning.

**Code:**

Inside functions.php:

```
<?php

  //the api endpoint declaration
  add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route(
        'theme/v2',   // namespace
        '/homepage',  // route
        array(                  // options
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'build_home',
        )
    );
  });

  //the callback for the wordpress api
  function build_home() {

    // this is the external API request, using their PHP library. 
    // I linked the library above. The request returns an object with a bunch of data
    include_once(get_template_directory()."/arena/arena.php");
    $arena = new Arena();
    $page = $arena->set_page(); 
    $per = 8; 
    $slug = 'concepts-bo-6ajlvpqg'; 
    $channel = $arena->get_channel($slug, array('page' => $page, 'per' => $per));

    //I'm passing the response from the external API (in $channel) to get_template part
    //get_template_part is then the output for the wordpress API request
    get_template_part('custom-home-template',null,array('channel'=>$channel));
 }

 ?>
```

Inside template part:

```
<?php
  $channel=$args["channel"];
  ?>

  <div id="concepts-box" class="bodycontent reg-width">
    <?php foreach ($channel->contents as $item) { if($item->class=="Image"){
      $img=$item->image["square"]["url"];
      ?>
    <div class="concept-wrapper">
      <!-- the line below is the one that triggers the error -->
      <img lozad src="<?=$img; ?>">
    </div>
    <?php }} ?>
  </div>
```

Full warning:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /filepath/wp-content/themes/theme/custom-home-template.php:63) in <b>/filepath/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php</b> on line <b>1372</b><br />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: That's the post I linked in my question. So no, not as far as I can tell. But I may be missing something.

Comment: Can you use the browser's tools to look at the response from the server?

Comment: I can go the URL for the api endpoint and see the response it gives me — is that what you mean? This is the full warning:
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /filepath/wp-content/themes/theme/custom-home-template.php:63) in <b>/filepath/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php</b> on line <b>1372</b><br />

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com - you might have better luck here

Comment: Your callback function needs to _return_ a value, not create output directly (which is what happens, when you call your template with `get_template_part`)  - see https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value Easiest solution here would be that you use output buffering to capture the output created by that get_template_part call, and then return it.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I added output buffering and the warning is now gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on Wordpress SO — [link here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381739/headers-already-sent-error-with-get-template-part-in-rest-api-call/381745?noredirect=1#comment554068_381745). The issue was I was treating `get_template_part` as an API response instead of feeding it through output buffering into a variable